# Why the component I deploy to AWS Greengrass Core fails immediately after being deployed?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-iot-greengrass

I have developed a component that subscribes to a local broker in my Greengrass core device and also subscribed to the device shadow of the core device and updates it with data coming from the local broker.

All good, it works for me locally before I deploy it but once deployed it crashes and in CloudWatch I can see the following errors:

```
{
"timestamp": "2022-04-22 20:25:49.139",
"logLevel": "ERROR",
"traceId": "05e6b233-1b52-d773-d061-3c74057655ea",
"accountId": "***********",
"status": "Failure",
"eventType": "GetThingShadow",
"protocol": "MQTT",
"deviceShadowName": "MyName",
"topicName": "$aws/things/MyName/shadow/name/AWSManagedGreengrassV2Deployment/get",
"details": "No shadow exists with name: 'MyName~AWSManagedGreengrassV2Deployment'"
}
```

The second one:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2022-04-22 20:26:08.479",
    "logLevel": "ERROR",
    "accountId": "********",
    "status": "Success",
    "eventType": "UpdateJobExecution",
    "protocol": "MQTT",
    "clientId": "MyName",
    "jobId": "d1a10592-7d03-4cc8-aeca-1a615dc562e0",
    "topicName": "$aws/things/MyName/jobs/d1a10592-7d03-4cc8-aeca-1a615dc562e0/namespace-aws-gg-deployment/update",
    "details": "The destination status is FAILED. The request status is SUCCESS."
}
```

What could cause these issues? Can somebody give me a clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to my problem.

It was the fact that the component I deployed has a different Java version compared to the one that the Greengrass Core is running.

I hope that helps somebody.